# linq how can I fill a dictionary object

Tags: c#, linq

I had this before and I've eliminated the KVP and simply have the Dictionary property.

### Before:

```
public class GranuleAttributes
{
    public Dictionary<string, KVP> attributes { get; set; }
}
public class KVP
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

### After:

```
public class GranuleAttributes
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Before I filled my Dictionary with the following LINQ:

```
  attributes =
    (
        from attrRow in granuleGroup.First()
        select new KVP()
        {
            ID = Convert.ToString(attrRow["AttributeID"],
            Value = (string)attrRow["AttributeValue"]
        }
    ).ToDictionary(p => p.ID)
```

How would I fill my attributes object now?

### Update

Okay full disclosure, here is the code:

```
var groups = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
    .GroupBy(dr => new { ID = (int)dr["id"] })
    .GroupBy(g => g.Key.ID);

response.attributes = (
    from granuleGroup in groups
    let granuleRow = granuleGroup.First().First()
    select new USpaceDataAttributes()
    {
        id = (int)granuleRow["id"],
        endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(granuleRow["endDate"]),
        startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(granuleRow["startDate"]),
        type = !DBNull.Value.Equals(granuleRow["type"]) ? (string)granuleRow["type"] : "",
        attributes =
        (
            from attrRow in granuleGroup.First()
            select new KVP()
            {
                ID = !DBNull.Value.Equals(attrRow["AttributeID"]) ? Convert.ToString(attrRow["AttributeID"]) : string.Empty,
                Value = !DBNull.Value.Equals(attrRow["AttributeValue"]) ? (string)attrRow["AttributeValue"] : string.Empty
            }
        ).ToSerializableDictionary(p => p.ID)
    }
).ToList();
```

Then I have my own class that like `public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TVal> : Dictionary<TKey, TVal>, IXmlSerializable, ISerializable` with the following extension method.

```
#region ExtensionMethod
public static class CollectionExtensions
{

    public static SerializableDictionary<TKey, T> ToSerializableDictionary<TKey, T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var dict = new SerializableDictionary<TKey, T>();
        foreach (T item in seq)
        {
            TKey key = keySelector(item);
            dict.Add(key, item);
        }

        return dict;
    }
} 
#endregion
```

Comment: What type `granuleGroup` has?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Update with full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need selecting anonymous object or KVP object

```
attributes = granuleGroup.First()
                 .ToDictionary(r => Convert.ToString(r["AttributeID"]),
                               r => Convert.ToString(r["AttributeValue"]));
```

---

Update: You should add value selector to your extension method

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{    
    public static SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToSerializableDictionary<T, TKey, TValue>(
       this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, Func<T, TValue> valueSelector)
    {
        var dict = new SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            TKey key = keySelector(item);
            TValue value = valueSelector(item);
            dict.Add(key, value);
        }

        return dict;
    }
}
```

Comment: update with full code. notice how `ToDictionary` is actually `ToSerializableDictionary` I had left that out for simplicity sake, but maybe it's relevant

Comment: @capdragon update answer to match your updated question. Just add value selector to extension method, and you can use `ToSerializableDictionary` instead of `ToDictionary` in my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
attributes =
    (
        from attrRow in granuleGroup.First()
        select new {            
            Key = Convert.ToString(attrRow["AttributeID"],
            Value = (string)attrRow["AttributeValue"]
        }
    ).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)
```

Comment: can't figure out why it now gives me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Dictionary<string,AnonymousType#1>' to 'Dictionary<string,string>'`

Comment: okay, update with full code. notice `ToDictionary` is actually `ToSerializableDictionary` I had left that out for simplicity sake, but maybe it's relevant.